# extract time portion from BeginTime property of reminder class

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Situation :
i am creating a reminder app , i have two pages page1 (for displaying reminders) and page2(for accepting reminder data from user)

my page1.xaml.cs is :

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }


    IEnumerable<ScheduledNotification> notifications;

    private void ResetItemsList()
    {
        notifications = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<ScheduledNotification>();

        NotificationListBox.ItemsSource = notifications;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs         e)
    {
        //Reset the ReminderListBox items when the page is navigated to.
        ResetItemsList();
    }
}
}
```

and this is my logic for creating present in page2.xaml.cs

```
        if ((bool)reminderRadioButton.IsChecked)
        {
            Reminder reminder = new Reminder(name);
            reminder.Title = titleTextBox.Text;
            reminder.Content = contentTextBox.Text;
            reminder.BeginTime = beginTime;
            reminder.ExpirationTime = expirationTime;
            reminder.RecurrenceType = recurrence;


            // Register the reminder with the system.
            ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
        }
```

PROBLEM : 
In page1.xaml i have binded value of `BeginTime` property to text property of a textblock . now whenever i run my app i get date as well as time in textblock control , i want only time to be displayed in the textblock what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format your string using [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). An example would be

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BeginTime, StringFormat='t'}"
```

The output format would be `2:18 PM`. You can modify the `StringFormat` string to what you like depending on how you want the output to appear. If one of the standard `StringFormat` specifier from the link above doesn't have the output you need, you can create a [custom one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).